# MS SQL Server -  связь "многие-ко-многим".

Tags: sql-server

**Здравствуйте!**

Имеем 2 таблицы: "Книга", "Автор".

Подразумевается, что один автор может быть авторами многих кних и 1 книга может быть написана несколькими авторами.

Я предполагаю тут связь многие-ко-многим.
Как учит МСДН, сделал промежуточную таблицу.. а дальше методом тыка т.к. начиная с пункта пятого ([Построение связи «многие ко многим»](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms178043.aspx)) я его не понял.

В итоге у меня получается что 1 книга может быть написана несколькими авторами, но 1  автор по прежнему может написать только 1 книгу.

Прилагаю код создания таблиц. MS Server 2005 Standart.

```
CREATE TABLE Author
(
    AuthorID INT  NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    AuthorFamilyName VARCHAR(100),
    AuthorName VARCHAR(50),
    AuthorPatronymicName VARCHAR(100),
    AuthorFIO VARCHAR(100)
)

--список издательств
-- 1 книга - 1 издательство
CREATE TABLE Publisher
(
    PublisherID INT  NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    PublisherName VARCHAR(100)
)

-- Обеспечение связи многие-ко-многим (авторы и книги)

CREATE TABLE AuthorsBooks
(
    --AuthorsBooksID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    AuthorID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    BookID INT
)

--Информация о книге
CREATE TABLE Book
(
    BookID INT  NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    BookTitle VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    BookAuthor INT  NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES AuthorsBooks, --ссылка на таблицу авторов
    BookYear INT,
    BookQuantityPages INT,
    BookPublisher INT  NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Publisher-- ссылка на таблицу издательства
)
```

Т.е. в промежуточнок таблицу 2 колонки - книгаИДН и АвторИДН, первичный ключ здесь Автор у меня.

**Подскажите, в чем я не прав?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Я бы составил кросс-таблицу не с составным первичным ключом, а с суррогатным, а `AuthorId` и `BookId` сделал бы внешними ключами:

```
CREATE TABLE AuthorsBooks
(
    Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    AuthorID INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Author(AuthorID),
    BookID INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Book(BookID
)
```

Почему имено с суррогатным ключом, а не с составным? Огромной разницы нет, но есть неогромная (взято [отсюда](http://baks.gaz.ru/oradoc/ora/ora368.htm)):

1. Люди часто пытаются изменять первичный ключ, чтобы исправить данные - использование неизменного суррогатного ключа решает проблему каскадных изменений, поскольку первичный ключ изменять не придется никогда - только 3 столбца данных, которые больше нигде не хранятся.
2. Проще написать:

   ```
   select * from p, c where p.primary_key = c.foreign_key
   ```

чем

```
    select * from p, c where p.id1 = c.fk1 and p.id2 = c.fk2 and p.id3 = c.fk3

  да и работает первый запрос быстрее.
```

Comment: Поскольку кросс нужен только для того, чтобы связывать две таблицы, то собственный суррогатный ключ там, как мне кажется, не нужен. Я, например, навскидку не могу придумать запроса, в котором надо было бы что-то искать по суррогатному ключу этой кросс-таблицы. В моем варианте надо бы еще создать индекс по BookID, а в вашем - два индекса. По одному на каждый внешний ключ. 
Поэтому в вашем варианте я вижу два минуса по сравнению с моим: 

1) лишнее поле;
2) три индекса вместо двух;

Comment: и, кстати, уберите из таблицы второй первичный ключ :)

Comment: Про первичный ключ вы абсолютно правы!

Вопрос возник - В последнем примере тоже присутствует 2 первичных ключа, и програма выдает ошибку.Получается, что тут тоже 2 Первичных ключа. Может я чего недопонимаю?

Comment: >и, кстати, уберите из таблицы второй первичный ключ :)

ай, косяк))) спасибо)

Answer (score 2):

Если связь многие к многим, то в кросс-таблице первичный ключ должен быть составным и включать в себя оба поля. Еще неплохо бы сделать их FOREGN KEY

```
CREATE TABLE AuthorsBooks
(
    AuthorID INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Author(AuthorID),
    BookID INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Book(BookID), 
    PRIMARY KEY (AuthorID, BookID)
)
```

Comment: я попробовал ваш вариант, н ополучается интересная картина - таблица AuthorsBooks ссылается на таблицу Book и наоборот. Т.е. невозможно создать сначала ни ту ни другую таблицу, т.к. она ссылается соответсвенно на другую. Как можно выйти из этого положения?

Comment: Да ничего особенного. Сначала создаются таблицы Книга и Автор. Потом создается таблица связки

    CREATE TABLE AuthorsBooks
    (
        AuthorID INT NOT NULL,
        BookID INT NOT NULL, 
        PRIMARY KEY (AuthorID, BookID)
    )

Теперь указываем, что эти поля вообще то связаны по внешним ключам

    ALTER TABLE AuthorsBooks WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT FK1 FOREIGN KEY(AuthorID)
    REFERENCES Author(AuthorID)

    ALTER TABLE AuthorsBooks WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT FK2 FOREIGN KEY(BookID)
    REFERENCES Book(BookID)